# Relativity of simultaneity in Galileo's Leaning Tower of Pisa experiment

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, reference-frames, free-fall, equivalence-principle

Galileo's conclusion can be roughly summed up as: objects of different masses, when dropped from the same height, descend in the same time interval, independent on their masses (neglecting friction). That is to say, they reach the ground *simultaneously*.

However, we know from Special Relativity that simultaneity depends of the reference system that one chooses. Is that also applicable to this case? If so, what exactly is meant by *simultaneously* in this context?

Comment: +1 @RobinEkman, "simultaneous" is a red herring here.  The important result of Galileo's experiment was that the amount of time it takes an object to fall from a given height is independent of the mass of the object.  The test masses don't have to be dropped at the same time if you have the means to measure, record, and compare the elapsed times of each experimental drop.

Comment: Yes, and more generally the equivalence principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of talking about simultaneity you can talk about the measured time between dropping the object and falling. Indeed if [an astronaut drops a feather from his left hand and a hammer from his right](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5C5_dOEyAfk) on the Moon, an observer in motion relative to the astronaut will not consider the astronaut to drop the objects simultaneously, nor agree that they hit the ground simultaneously. However, the observer will measure the *same time* for the objects to fall. This is a more clear statement of the equivalence principle: motion in gravitational fields is independent of the particle's mass. (Gravitational and inertial mass are equal.)

(Note that because of time dilation the observer will not agree with the astronaut how long it took. )

Comment: So you're saying, if I pass by the moon in my space shuttle moving at near-light speed, i will not see the feather and hammer hitting the ground simultaneously (due to the SR relativity of simultaneity)?

Comment: This is exactly the point I was making in my comment that started with "Things would still drop simultaneously."

Comment: Yes, but you will also not see the astronaut drop them simultaneously.

Comment: @RobinEkman "...so the time difference you observed would be constant" (between the dropping part and the landing part of the experiment).

Comment: and if there is a clock on the hammer that stops when it hits the ground, that would also show a different time? (i mean different from the clock of the rocket guy and the one of the astronaut dropping them)